# loop through excel column and write new value in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas in python and have an excel file with one column that includes a header called test_name. I would like to loop through each row of that column and update the value. I have written the code that pulls each value from the column but I'm not sure how to write a new value back to the cell.

```
import pandas as pd

orders = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

if orders.columns[0] == 'test_name':
    cols = [0]
    test_names = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', usecols=cols)

    for name in test_names.values:
        print(name[0])
        
        new_value = 3333
        #write new_value back to the current cell.

else:
    print('Column test_name not found ')
```

Comment: I think you are doing some of your work here in a way that is unlike what I've seen or done with pandas... For example, it seems unncessary to hit the excel file twice to pull the data in when you could just from the get-go do `pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',usecols=['test name']`. The bigger thing, though, is your loop through the values, which is very non-standard. What I think would be better is to make another column that has gets mapped from the first, so you'd have some function or formula to get from current to new, and then `.apply()` to get it. Then write the new column itself to excel.

Comment: Also, specific question - does the excel file have any other data other than this one column in it? It is easy to save a pandas dataframe as an excel file (overwriting the existing file), but will be more complex if you want to keep some other things from the original excel file.

Comment: The excel file will have 20+ columns. I am trying to create a proof of concept. The program will need to take the value of each row in the test_name column, reach out to a database to retrieve a test_code and then override the name in the row. I guess an easier approach would be to load the entire column into a data frame, update the data frame and then add a new column containing all the codes. I am currently learning python, so I am new to it's capabilities.

Comment: if the whole excel file is just a table (that is, you don't have other tabs with some formatted report, or other random cells), i think the easier approach is to pull in the entire table into a dataframe, update the one column, and the export back to excel. You can also likely get the data from your database into pandas and then use `pandas.merge()` to do a join between the tables to see what the new value should be.